# Why doesn't new operator creates chain structure?

Tags: php, constructor, chain

Assuming `GeneralNews()` returns `this` and `CreateInstance()` return `this`, the first 2 methods work but the final one fails.

I'm not understanding why?

```
$objGeneralNews = new GeneralNews();  

$arrDataList = $objGeneralNews->SetWhere('news01date="2011-01-01"')->GetFrontList();
var_dump( $arrDataList ); //This method works

$arrDataList = GeneralNews::CreateInstance()->SetWhere('news01date="2011-01-01"')->GetFrontList();
var_dump( $arrDataList ); //This method works  

$arrDataList = (new GeneralNews())->SetWhere('news01date="2011-01-01"')->GetFrontList();
var_dump( $arrDataList ); //This method doesn't works
```

Class Code GeneralNews:

```
class GeneralNews {         
    public function GeneralNews(){
        return this;
    } 

    public static function CreateInstance(){  
        $strClassName = 'GeneralNews';   
        return new $strClassName;  
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the code for CreateInstance() and constructor function of GeneralNews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, directly referencing objects of `new` expressions [does not work in PHP 5.3](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kMx0V8), but [does work in PHP 5.4](http://codepad.viper-7.com/drqI57).

Comment: hm... seems you r correct. thnx for the quick link... it helped.